# Adding 2 simple aspx pages to Sharepoint Site Definition

Tags: asp.net, xml, sharepoint

I am working on a sharepoint website which is built upon a Site Definition in visual studio.

All i would like to do is simply add 2 aspx pages to this Site Definition. Kindly reply how can i accomplish this.

Do i add new aspx files under Site Template folder or add a new Feature perhaps? so that when i deploy my solution (.wsp) the two aspx pages appear on the site.

Comment: Before you do this, you need to understand how "simple ASPX pages" work in SharePoint. See [Creating Application Pages for SharePoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231581.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you create a [module feature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms453137.aspx), add the two .aspx pages to the feature and then add this feature to the site definition.

Maybe also helpful: [How to: Provision a File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms441170.aspx)